# google dfp does not show up ads continuosuly

Tags: google-dfp

I have created a ad unit in google dfp and line item/order with clicks of 10000 with 3 days campaign. For one day it was showing the ad only once in a while in ad slot in my webpage. After that the rate increased but still sometimes it may show the ad slot on my webpage empty. Does anybody know how to setup or do some scripting so that once it starts showing up, it will show up continuously for anybody who visits the webpage until the campaign or that targets are achieved. On web there are discussions about auto-collapse of divs when ad is not fetched, but I want to keep the space for an ad continuously, it should not appear empty if ad is not fetched.

Code in website looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en-us">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>Widgets Magazine</title> 
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>
</script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- Anywhere -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-xxx-0' style='width:250px; height:250px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-xxx-0'); });
</script>
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript code most likely is okay. The problem is on the server side, in the settings of your line item.

Based on the number of clicks and the length of the campaign you have configured, DfP will estimate the delivery speed to evenly distribute the ad impressions and/or clicks for the duration of the campaign.

In order to always serve an ad, you either:

- create a new line item of type *network* or similar where you can configure to fulfill 100% of the remaining impressions (see [Line item types and their delivery priorities](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/79283)), or
- set the delivery speed of your line item to *as fast as possible* (see [Change the delivery speed of a line item](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/82244))

Note that DfP will completely stop serving the campaign once the delivery target (the number of clicks or ad impressions) has been reached.